What is causing NoMethodError?
I wrote this code for an exercise in pentesterlab:
require 'httparty'
require 'base64'
URL = 'http://ptl-a4b5e023-f4db1f7c.libcurl.so/'

def login(username)
  res = HTTParty.post(URL+'login.php',body:{username:username,password: 'Password1'}>

  return res.headers["set-cookie"].split("=")[1]
end

cookie =  login("administ")
signature1 = Base64.decode64(cookie).split("__")[1]

def xor(str1, str2)
  ret =""
  str1.split(//).each_with_index do |c, i|
    ret[i] = (str1[i].ord ^ str2[i].ord).chr
  end
  return ret
end

username2 = xor("rator\00\00\00",signature1)

cookie2 = login(username2).gsub("%2B","+")
puts cookie2
signature2 = Base64.decode64(cookie2).split("__")[1]
puts signature2

puts Base64.encode64("administrator--#{signature2}")

And I got this error:
ruby cbcccccc.rb 
cbcccccc.rb:17:in `block in xor': undefined method `[]' for nil (NoMethodError)

    ret[i] = (str1[i].ord ^ str2[i].ord).chr
                                ^^^
    from cbcccccc.rb:16:in `each'
    from cbcccccc.rb:16:in `each_with_index'
    from cbcccccc.rb:16:in `xor'
    from cbcccccc.rb:22:in `<main>'

What is causing the error?

The problem is that str2 in your xor method is nil.
The value for str2 is created here:
signature1 = Base64.decode64(cookie).split("__")[1]

You got a nil value because you attempted to access an array past its bounds. From this, we can infer that Base64.decode64(cookie).split("__") resulted in an array that was less than 2 items long.
You need to investigate the value of Base64.decode64(cookie) and determine why it hasn't met your expectation of containing the substring __.
